# filter array of objects if properties are in another array and values are true

Tags: javascript, filter

The following is a sample that yields the desired output.

```js
const data = [
                { itemID: '300', status: 'active', inventoryFlag: true, certifiedFlag: false, donateFlag: true },
                { itemID: '400', status: 'inactive', inventoryFlag: true, certifiedFlag: true, donateFlag: false },
                { itemID: '500', status: 'active', inventoryFlag: false, certifiedFlag: false, donateFlag: false },
                { itemID: '600', status: 'active', inventoryFlag: false, certifiedFlag: true, donateFlag: true },
                { itemID: '700', status: 'inactive', inventoryFlag: false, certifiedFlag: true, donateFlag: false }
            ];
           
document.getElementById("data").innerText = JSON.stringify(data.filter(o => o.inventoryFlag || o.donateFlag));
```

```html
<textarea id="data" rows="50" cols="100"></textarea>
```

I'm trying to find a way to list the filter-by flags in a separate array and then use that in the `.filter()` somehow to get the same result set as the above code.

For example, here are the flags to use for filtering AND at least one of the values must be true in the object to be included in the final dataset -

```
const flags = ['inventoryFlag', 'donateFlag'];
```

As a start, I tried this but it didn't do anything:

```
const filteredData = data.filter(o => flags.includes(Object.keys(o)));
```

Comment: `Object.keys(o)` returns an array of strings, so you need to check if any of the values in `flags` is contained in that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the `filter`, use the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to detect if any of the property keys of an entry, that are contained in the `flags` array, have the a value of `true`.

```js
const data = [
  { itemID: '300', status: 'active', inventoryFlag: true, certifiedFlag: false, donateFlag: true },
  { itemID: '400', status: 'inactive', inventoryFlag: true, certifiedFlag: true, donateFlag: false },
  { itemID: '500', status: 'active', inventoryFlag: false, certifiedFlag: false, donateFlag: false },
  { itemID: '600', status: 'active', inventoryFlag: false, certifiedFlag: true, donateFlag: true },
  { itemID: '700', status: 'inactive', inventoryFlag: false, certifiedFlag: true, donateFlag: false }
];

const flags = ['inventoryFlag', 'donateFlag'];

const result = data.filter(entry => 
  flags.some(flag => entry[flag] === true)
);

console.log(result);
```